# Generalisation of Visitor Pattern is impossible?

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

**Is there a way of full generalistation of visitor pattern?**

I concluded that fully generising Visitor pattern is impossible in JAVA if I want also generalise the return value. Only possible to make generic either the Visitor/Visitable or the ReturnValue.

---

**Example1 - Return value is generic but the Visitor/Visitable is not:**

```
public abstract class PaymentType { //Visitable
    public abstract <T> T accept(PaymentTypeVisitor<T> visitor);
}
public interface PaymentTypeVisitor<T> {
    public T visit(CommissionedPaymentType commissionedPaymentType);
    public T visit(SalariedPaymentType salariedPaymentType);
    public T visit(HourlyPaymentType hourlyPaymentType);
}
```

**Example2 - Visitor/Visitable is generic, but the return value is not (unsafe generic):**

```
public interface Visitor<V extends Visitor<V, A>, A extends Visitable<V, A>> {
}
public interface Visitable<V extends Visitor<V, A>, A extends Visitable<V, A>> {
    public abstract <R> R accept(V visitor); //Unsafe generic
}
```

_

```
public interface AddEmployeeError extends Error, Visitable<AddEmployeeErrorVisitor, AddEmployeeError> {

}
public interface AddEmployeeErrorVisitor extends Visitor<AddEmployeeErrorVisitor, AddEmployeeError> {
    //Unsafe generics
    <R> R visit(IdAlreadyExistsValidationError idAlreadyExistsValidationError);
    <R> R visit(NameAlreadyExistsValidationError nameAlreadyExistsValidationError);
}
```

_

```
public class AddEmployeeUseCaseValidationErrorFormatter implements AddEmployeeErrorVisitor {
    @Override
    protected String format(AddEmployeeError error) {
        return error.accept(this);
    }

    //Unsafe return type
    @Override
    public String visit(IdAlreadyExistsValidationError idAlreadyExistsValidationError) {
        return String.format("%s already owns this id!", idAlreadyExistsValidationError.nameOfExistingUser);
    }

    //Unsafe return type
    @Override
    public String visit(NameAlreadyExistsValidationError nameAlreadyExistsValidationError) {
        return String.format("Name already exists with id: %s", nameAlreadyExistsValidationError.idOfExistingUser);
    }

}
```

I found this case here: http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.fr/2009/01/visitor-pattern-generic-and-still-type.html

Comment: Well I think you cannot force the type since you cannot force the methods present on the visitor

Comment: Yes, but if you check 1.st Example, you can force by adding T return type for all visit method, but in 2nd Example you have no way

Comment: Because you have a well-defined visitor, not a generic visitor type which you don't know anything about.

Comment: OK, so this why that is impossible what I want? So my original assume is correct that this is impossible?

Comment: Well yes I think it's impossible simply because you need at least a visitor interface with a bunch of methods on it. If you try abstracting it so much that you don't even know what methods there are on the visitor, I can hardly imagine how you will possibly be able to even write the visitable